# Push Notification in woklight

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-runtime

I am not able to get actually how push notification works in worklight.

1. how to pass my device details for the server after registration with GCM,APNS.
2. how can I toggle with on/off of push notification within the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Read both:

   - Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html?lang=en
   - Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/
2. The Worklight/MobileFirst Platform Foundation framework takes care of that for you.

   - In the case of Event Source-based notifications, a notification can be sent by the userId or other types of identifications. This information is stored automatically in the server's database. On your end, when implementing the adapter logic to send the notifications, you can use various APIs (see the Knowledge Center link above) to decide to whom/how notifications are sent.
   - Also in Tag-based notifications, you can either auto-subscribe or have the user tap a button to subscribe; this sends the data to the server's database, and again in the adapter logic you can then iterate on this list of users/devices to send the notification(s).
3. To toggle notifications on and off you can use the subscribe/un-subscribe API methods. Review the developer canter tutorials and their accompanying sample applications.